# Adding compiler commands with preprocessors

Tags: c++

I have a header only library that uses Open MP however that requires the /openmp compiler flag. Looking around their didn't seem to be anything that could do something like this. Something like this:

```
#pragma compiler("-openmp")
```

Its mostly to make the users life easier because they would not have to include the command themselves.

Comment: Why? Does this apply in C as well?

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything about `#pragma` is specific to the compiler.

Most compilers do not provide a catch-all command line modification facility because it is difficult in general to change parameters without violating internal invariants and expectations. It would make the compiler unstable.

A more typical solution would be something like this:

```
#ifndef _OPENMP
#   error Please pass the -openmp or equivalent compiler flag for my library.
#endif
```

Comment: I see. I guess I would still have to tell people to use the flag (along with that error message if not). Thanks.